# Google+ HTTP API returns less activities than supposed to

Tags: google-plus

I've been using Google Plus HTTP API for several weeks now and I'm experiencing a strange issue.

When I try to retrieve public activities from this community: https://plus.google.com/communities/115653528125420367824, I always get 4 results, no more. I've tried increasing the maxResult parameter of the request but it doesn't change anything...

And when I use the nextPageToken to retrieve the missing activities, the "items" field of the response is empty.

You can try it yourself with the Google APIs Explorer here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=115653528125420367824&collection=public you will see that only 4 activites are returned and the next page of result is empty.

This is really strange and happened recently, it used to work fine. Maybe it is caused by the fact that the content of some activities of this community contains a stringified JSON object. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The [activities](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities) methods are only supported for retrieving posts by users and Google+ Pages. They are not supported for use with Communities and should not be expected to work correctly. There is definitely no guarantee that this behavior while it might have worked or currently works in some cases today will continue to work in the future.